# Embed javascript component in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

How can I embed in a template a script like this in a meteorjs application (with iron-router)?

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget({
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "FX:SPX500",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "exchange",
  "theme": "White",
  // other stuffs...
});
</script>
```

I got the widget snippet [here](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/).
[Here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SyTsmpHKPvMtotGiL/TradingView) is my sample code: the application does not show any chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Iron Router, inserting head content is not currently practical.   It will create a situation of double head tags.

The easiest thing to do, is simply create a JS file with your script content in it.   Meteor will automatically include it in the head portion of your app along with anything other JS.

In reality though, I would probably put this in the template as

```
Template.app.onRendered(function() {
new TradingView.widget({
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "FX:SPX500",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "exchange",
  "theme": "White",
  // other stuffs...

});
```